How to make tikz diagram in quarto output?
Hello I've been exploring my options to build diagrams with math notation in them for html output.
I was exploring the quarto_tikz extension but keeping running into issues rendering.
When running the sample script from the github:
---
title: "Tikz Example"
filters:
  - tikz
format:
  html: {}
tikz:
  cache: true
---

This renders TiKZ diagrams in markdown.

::: {#fig-example .test-class}
```{.tikz  embed_mode="link" scale=3 filename="example"}
%%|format: svg
\node[draw, circle] (A) at (0,0) {A};
\node[draw, circle] (B) at (2,2) {$\phi$};
\node[draw, circle] (C) at (4,0) {C};
\node[draw, circle] (seven) at (5,1) {888888};
\draw[->] (A) -- (B);
\draw[->] (B) -- (C);
\draw[->] (C) -- (A);
```

Rendering TikZ DAGs is easy.
:::

See, that was not so bad.

I get the following errors:
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
'dvisvgm' is not recognized as an internal or external command
cp: cannot stat './images/example-1.svg': No such file or directory
I downloaded dvisvgm from https://dvisvgm.de/ but don't really know what to do with files it provides on windows.
Update:
I added the dvisvgm to my path. Now I get an ERROR: MiKTeX session could not be initialized
